# How to read data between two html tags as text

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on a project which needs to extract text form a predefined `div` tag.

My requirement is to send the content in the target `div` in a email body. I have to use `javascript` or `php` for this task.

The Process :
When a given link will be clicked; a `javascript` function will trigger and read that target `div`. The content of the `div` will be then submitted to server in dynamic form.

What options I have to get this task done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming that you have something that looks like

```
<a href="#" onClick="someClickHandler(); return false;">Click Here</a>
<div id="foo">Hello World!</div>
```

I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someClickHandler() {
        var text = $("#foo").text();
        $.get("url_on_the_server", {some_query_parameter_name: text}, function(response){
            // do something with the response you get back from the server
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here's what this is doing:

- The `onClick` attribute causes the `someClickHandler` function to be called when the link is clicked.  Because we put `return false` in that attribute, the browser will not try to follow the link; instead when clicked it will just execute the click handler and stop.
- Saying `$("#foo")` finds the element on the page with an `id` of "foo", as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).  Saying `$("#foo").text()` returns everything inside that div as text, as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- The `$.get` call is explained at depth in the jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  Basically you're making an AJAX request to the server and passing the text from the div as a query parameter.  The function you pass to `$.get` defines what you do with the response you get back from the server.

Of course, you could also use the [jQuery click method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of manually setting the `onClick` attribute yourself, but I figured that this way would be somewhat more intuitive for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `text()` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/text/)) would let you get the text inside the div.

```
var thetext = jQuery('div#foo').text();
```

You could then use its `post()` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) to send the data to a PHP script for emailing.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the `innerHTML` of the div. So if your div is div_obj:

```
var div_obj = document.getElementById("...");
alert(div_obj.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById( ID_OF_DIV ).innerHTML;
```

should do it if I'm not mistaken. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a wonderful website for information on web programming.

Comment: Since when is [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom) traversing [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax)? Your answer a bit implies that. It are two separate subjects, Ajax and the code snippet you posted.

Comment: You are quite right. Sorry for the mistake. I assumed the need to post changes back to the site in my response.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I'd give the div an id and then use the innerHTML method to get its contents.

After that, you could use XMLHttpRequest to submit the contents to the server.